# Teplace special (HTML) characters to the space

Tags: php, preg-replace, strip-tags

I have a problem with replacing HTML characters, before inserting data I'm doing something with my string:

```
strip_tags(mb_substr($record['text'],0,100, 'utf-8'));
```

But, I have a problem, result of this.

That my text before, I've i used strip_tags() function:

```
Астрономы описали орбиту гипотетической планеты Солнечной системы <br>Небесные механики из Лабора
```

> Астрономы описали орбиту гипотетической планеты Солнечной системыНебесные механики из Лабора

But I need something like that:

> Астрономы описали орбиту гипотетической планеты Солнечной системы. Небесные механики из Лабора